# Site thumbnail in links shows beta design

Tags: bug, design

I was talking to someone on Skype and sent them the link for ELL. The thumbnail image shows the old beta logo (the letters "ELL" in a light blue speech bubble). Oddly enough, on Facebook it correctly shows the new logo. I would have thought it was the same process to get the thumbnail image for both.

Can this be looked into please?